# Hiding website file extensions (.html) from search bar without altering page anchors (<a href="example.html" >)

Tags: html, .htaccess

Last year I attempted to alter my .htaccess file in order to hide file extensions from the search bar, however, this only seemed to work if I removed the file extensions from the pages anchor tags as well.

I would really much prefer to not alter the actual anchor tags within my .html documents, as I may have folders with the exact same name as a file, like so:

mysite.com/index.html/**something**/otherpage.html

mysite.com/index.html/**something**.html

Is there a way to just hide the .html extention from the search bar, without altering my anchor tags?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked into mod_rewrite?

Comment: I tried a few things with no luck. I'm not sure how to properly write the condition/rule for the rewrite engine.

Answer (score 0):

To hide `.html` extensions you can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit your anchor tags to remove the `.html` extension as you have. Then you can use a rule like this to rewrite the URI to a html file. This also will ignore the directory.

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ $1.html [L]
```